Goldberger-Wise Mechanism in Randall-Sundrum I Model
Can someone explain the Goldberger-Wise mechanism for radius stabilization in the Randall-Sundrum model? I am reading their original paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9907447, but I am a bit confused about the physical meaning of this mechanism.
More specifically, why don't Goldberger and Wise introduce any potential for the bulk scalar field in the bulk itself? Why do they introduce the potential only at the branes?
An intuitive understanding of this mechanism is what I am looking for. Thanks
